# Difference between "female" and "woman"

Tags: word-usage, nouns

I haven't been able to find any good articles describing rules (or patterns) specifying use of the words *female* and *woman*.

Let's take the following sentences as an example:

> (assuming we have a man and a woman)
>
> - The *woman* pointed the gun at the man
> - The *female* pointed the gun at the man

**the second sentence sounds very odd to me though.*

And what about *male doctor*; shall we then say *female doctor* or *woman doctor*?

Can you please provide any rules / patterns (I hope there are some) specifying usage of *female* and *woman*?

Comment: May we know what your native language is, Tom?

Comment: My native language is Polish

Comment: _Female_, used as noun, could result offensive. The _Corpus of Contemporary American English_ has 46 sentences with _woman doctor_, and 28 sentences with _female doctor_.

Comment: Something none of the answers have mentioned yet: *woman* refers to a female human, while *female* can describe non-humans.

Comment: @snailplane But that aspect of it is something obvious that Tom likely already knows.

Comment: *Male* and *female* can apply to humans or to animals, whereas *man* and *woman* are only human.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The words *male* and *female* are used as classifications (such as in anthropology, or medicine), and they can be used as adjectives as readily as nouns. The words *man* and *woman* are more personal descriptors of individuals.

When using these words to describe the subjects of a scientific study, we might find either of these:

> •The control group consisted of 26 female and 18 male patients.
>   •The control group consisted of 26 women and 18 men.

You are right about how your second example sentence sounds "off", but that's because you've mixed the two words:

> •The **woman** pointed the gun at the **man**. (sounds normal)
>   •The **female** pointed the gun at the **man**. (sounds awkward)
>   •The **woman** pointed the gun at the **male**. (also sounds awkward)
>   •The **female** pointed the gun at the **male**. (sounds acceptable)

However, context could very well override that general guidance. Some of the sentences I've labeled as *awkward* may sound funny on their own, but they could be just fine in the middle of a lengthy testimony during a courtroom trial, where a long series of questions has set up a scene - i.e., something like this:

> "What did you see in the room?"
>   *"There was a woman with a gun, and two people in the doorway."*
>   "Could you tell if those two people were male or female?"
>   *"Yes."*
>   "And what did you notice?"
>   *"There was one male, and one female."*
>   "And what happened next?"
>   *"The woman pointed the gun at the female."*

I think that last sentence reads just fine in that context, because the preceding dialog has made it rather easy to follow along.

Comment: *Female pointed the gun at the man* is acceptable, when the man is an innocent bystander, and the female is a criminal suspect. The speaker is emotionally distanced from the female, but identifies with the man.

Comment: @Kaz: Perhaps so, although, as I explained, I would expect that to be conveyed somehow by the surrounding context; I very much doubt I'd use that sentence on its own. Also, if I was to use that wording, I'd use an article, I think: _"**A** female pointed a gun at the man."_

Answer (score 5):

*Female* and *male* are useful in cases where it is not clear, or the speaker doesn’t want to say, whether or not the person referred to is a juvenile. You will sometimes find them used in, for example, police reports. However, where the age of the person is known, it’s preferable to use the relevant term, such as *woman, girl* or *young woman*, or *man, boy, lad* or *young man*.

When it comes to describing professions, questions of equality influence the language we use. It is advisable to refer to a doctor simply as a doctor. You can always say whether the doctor is a man or a woman later in the conversation if the need arises.

Comment: Indeed. At least in the US, a '*female doctor*' is often a euphemism for a gynecologist.

Answer (score 3):

*Female* is a word only defining the **gender**.
On the other hand, *woman* means a female who is also an **adult**.

### Usage

*Female* is rarely used, and usually used only in formal written English.
*Woman* is used quite commonly, as illustrated by *your* example.
If the person concerned is not an adult but a female, people usually use  *girl* or *young woman*.

Same for 'man' and 'male'.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar thing happens in Japanese. The Japanese word for woman is *onna*, corresponding to the character 女.  But if you simply call someone *onna* (for instance *ano onna ...*: *that woman ...*) it is abrupt, and offensive to that woman and the person you're talking to. People do not say this. The word used is *onna-no hito* (女の人), at the very least, or other words like *josei*　（女性）. However, in news reports, the word *onna* will often be used by itself to refer to a criminal suspect. It is not rude in that situation, but rather it is analogous to when English-speaking police or reporters say *female suspect*.  *"According to the security camera footage, the female suspect entered the building at 15:03 ..."*  "*The suspect is described a female between 35 and 40, five foot three, wearing ...*"  *"There were two perpetrators, a male and a female. The male was armed with a semi-automatic weapon ..."*  But it would be strange to use *female* to refer to a woman in everyday speech.  The following are inappropriate and weird. *My boss is a nice female*.  *There is a female at the front desk, asking for Mr. Jones*.

So that is the essence of *female* versus *woman*, when *female* is used to refer to a woman: the speaker is placing some kind of mental distance between him or herself and the subject, and not identifying with the woman as a fellow person.